# Confused about Trait Bounding in functions Rust

Tags: function, audio, rust, traits, gtk4

first post on here so apologies if I don't give enough information to get a clear picture.

I'm attempting to write a basic VST in Rust, the example I'm following has used a deprecated gtk method to actually build out the app and so I'm having to rewrite it. The thing I'm confused about is trait bounding (I think it's trait bounding) in functions.

How the function is written in the example:

```
fn run_main<Module: AudioModule>() { 
    //Stuff going on in here using Module::
}
```

What is going on here? Why am I doing this? Is there another way to achieve the same thing here?

I need to rewrite this function and pass an &app argument into it but I'm not allowed to do that because the AudioModule and gtk_app aren't related in anyway.

I tried to do something like this:

```
fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    //Doing all my UI stuff 
    
    fn defining_module<Module: AudioModule>() {
        //Doing all my Module:: stuff
    }
}
```

But honestly I haven't got a clue what I'm doing. It's throwing a load of errors at me. And I'm at a loss. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74577235/edit) your question to include more details. As it is I'm having a hard time understanding where your problem lies. Maybe take a look at what a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is. Also a link to the example you're following if it's publicly available can't hurt.

Comment: Also, you should *very* likely read the Rust book. It's the most straightforward way to get you acquainted with every notion needed to understand traits and bounds.

Comment: Are you certain the function is not written: `fn run_main<Module: AudioModule>(module: Module) {...}`. The `trait` bound is saying is that the argument `module` must implements the functions of the `AudioModule` trait and that the function can only expect those functions. Hope that helps.